# Why does string not work here while char const* does?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Why does `string` not work here when I catch an error, and `char const*` does? What is the difference between the two?

```
try {
    throw "connection fail";

} catch( string e ) {
    if(e == "connection fail") {
        std::cout << "caught: " << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not throwing a `std::string`, so you can't catch one.

Comment: @tkausl Why is that not a string?

Comment: Not certain here, but I suspect the question is "Why does `catch` not follow the same conversion rules as function parameters?"

Comment: @SamitKapoor are you asking if `const char*` and `std::string` are different types?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes and why doesn't string work in catch.

Comment: @SamitKapoor Q1: Yes, they are different types.  Q2: Because they are different types.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  A *string-literal* is a `const char[N]`, not a `std::string`.

Comment: Do `throw "xxxx"s;`  - read more here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You're not throwing a std::string, so you can't catch one.

> Why is that not a string?

Because in C++, the perfidiously-misnamed string literals (that's what `"abc"` is) are not actually strings. A string literal allocates some static storage for the contents of the string, and evaluates as a `const char (&)[N]` type, i.e. a reference to an array of characters of a given fixed length. In most contexts, that reference decays to a `const char *`, which is a pointer to a `const char`, and has nothing to do with strings in any sensible interpretation of the term "string". This is an unfortunate legacy of C, where there were no strings either, and you passed a "string" by passing a pointer to the first character of a string, with the implicit assumption that the string has to be `'\0'`-terminated *and* of course couldn't contain NUL's (`'\0'`) since they were indistinguishable from a terminator.

To create a string, you must be explicit about it:

```
throw std::string("foo bar baz");
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
try {
    throw (std::string)"connection fail";

} catch( string e ) {
    if(e == "connection fail") {
        std::cout << "caught: " << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).